# Print all False parameters with comma

Tags: python, python-3.x

The types of parameters A, B, C, and D are boolean. Now I want to print the name when it is False. Is there any easy and beautiful way to do that?

```
comment = ''
count = 0
if not A:
  comment = 'A'
  count += 1
if not B:
  comment = f'{comment}, B' if comment else 'B'
  count += 1
if not C:
  comment = f'{comment}, C' if comment else 'C'
  count += 1
if not D:
  comment = f'{comment}, D' if comment else 'D'
  count += 1

if count > 2:
  comment = ', and'.join(comment.rsplit(',', 1))
  print(f'{comment} are False')
elif count > 1:
  comment = ' and'.join(comment.rsplit(',', 1))
  print(f'{comment} are False')
else:
  print(f'{comment} is False')
```

Output:

1. A is False
2. A and B are False
3. A, B, and C are False

Comment: Would all of them be `False`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary instead of variables. Then you can iterate through it:

```
bool_dict = {"A": True, "B": False, "C": True, "D": False}

false_keys = [key for key, value in bool_dict.items() if not value]
if len(false_keys) == 1:
    print(f"{false_keys[0]} is False")
elif len(false_keys) > 1:
    print(f"{', '.join(false_keys[:-1])} and {false_keys[-1]} are False")
```

Comment: Join on 1 element doesn't add the separator, so it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `split` to turn a comma-separated string into a list. Just use a `list` in the first place.

```
comment = []
count = 0
if not A:
    comment.append('A')
if not B:
    comment.append('B')
if not C:
    comment.append('C')
if not D:
    comment.append('D')

# Borrowing Daniel Geffen's code
count = len(comment)
if count == 1:
    print(f"{comement[0]} is False")
elif len(false_keys) > 1:
    print(f"{', '.join(comment[:-1])} and {comment[-1]} are False")
```

Daniel's answer comes from the recognition that instead of having separate boolean variables `A` et. al, use a single `dict` that maps a string to a boolean. If you already have those variables, you can build the `dict` like

```
d = {'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C, 'D': D}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some better code but it uses quite a lot of Python syntax you may not be familiar with. I hope you can learn more from it than just the answer to your question.

```
from random import randint

# Just get some random true/false's
a = randint(0, 1) == 1
b = randint(0, 1) == 1
c = randint(0, 1) == 1
d = randint(0, 1) == 1

# Make your values easy to work with
value_dict = {
    "a": a,
    "b": b,
    "c": c,
    "d": d
}

# Filter our dictiory, save the key of false values to a list
false_values = [
    key for key, val in 
    value_dict.items() 
    if val == False
]

if len(false_values) == 0:
    print("None are false")
elif len(false_values) == 1:
    print("{} is False".format(false_values[0]))
else:
    # This covers both 2 and more false values. 
    # If only 2 are false, there's no comma in between values. 
    print("{} and {} are False".format(
        ", ".join(false_values[:-1]),
        false_values[-1]
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not easy to read,but It is short:

```
bool_dict = {"A": True, "B": True, "C": True, "D": True}

# comment is a list,which contains all the name of variable which is False
comment = [i for i in bool_dict if bool_dict[i]==False]
print("{} and {} are False".format(",".join(comment[:-1]),comment[-1]) if len(comment)>1 else "{} is False".format(comment[0]) if len(comment) else "None of them is False")
```